# Why PHP session unset if more than one time refresh page

Tags: php

This is my code to check if user is logged in or not:

```
if (!$_SESSION['userInfo']['name'])
{
    Redirect('login.php');
}
```

and code to redirect the page is:

```
function Redirect($url)
{
    ob_start();
    header('location:'.$url);
    exit;
}
```

This code is working properly when i press the refresh button one time but when I press the refresh button more than one time then the session variable is unset and redirects to login page.

I am using this code with API that take almost 5-10 second to load the page.If i press refresh button before loading then it's happened.

What may be issue?

Comment: Add the code for the `Redirect()` function.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you may be clearing the value.Check you code..

Comment: And please add the code of login.php

Answer (score 0):

Try checking with `empty()`

```
if (empty($_SESSION['userInfo']['name']))
{
    Redirect('login.php');
}
```

**NOTE:** Please make sure you are not setting any value in `$_SESSION['userInfo']['name']` before login. Also after login you have to clear it.

Comment: @KajalSingh please try to print $_SESSION in login page, gives you hint

Comment: it works. Not work when i press refresh button more than one time before loading previous refresh action.

Comment: @KajalSingh Please try printing your session data in login and other pages so that you will get a hint

Answer (score 0):

Try using `isset()` function (ref: http://www.php.net/isset):

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['userInfo']['name']))
{
    Redirect('login.php');
}
```

And be sure to not clear the `$_SESSION` variable during a valid session, and still, be sure to clear it when the user logs out.

Maybe still use:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['userInfo']['name']))
{
    header('Location: login.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be omitting the code from your snippet, but are sure you starting your session?

```
session_start()
if (!isset($_SESSION['userInfo']['name']))
{
    Redirect('login.php');
}
```

Comment: are sure you starting your session? => if session not start then how it's work for login and logout process?

Comment: OK, Was just checking the basics first, as your question does NOT mention logout and also your login is broken.